# how to make 3d model of 2d image

Tags: modeling, image

I'm making a simulator and I have an image like a piece of chair and it's in 2d and I need to create a 3d model of that to be able to apply texture to it by three.js. So ,How can I convert a 2d image to a 3d model?

Comment: So far as I know, Blender cannot automatically do this.  If you have several images then you can use http://www.123dapp.com/catch and then use Blender to clean up the model.

Comment: How is this different then [your other question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19626/2217)?

Answer (score 4):

There is no software in the world that can do this, simply because a lot of (3D) information is missing in the 2D image. As MarcClintDion pointed out, it can be done out of multiple images from the same chair, but I doubt the result will please you. I'd encourage you to watch some basic Blender modeling tutorials and model the chair, you'll be done in 30 minutes and have a clean model.