# How to make 3D model and UV map from picture

Tags: materials, uv, three.js

I want to make a 3D model of an image but not for animation or other 3D stuff. I just need to have a model of my object to be able to apply textures to different faces of the object correctly.

[image]

In this picture I want to to apply the pattern with three.js. How should I do that?
Do I need to make a 3D model of that or UV map or both or something else?

Comment: I have found a instruction for that ,But I can't follow the steps. http://www.wikihow.com/Turn-a-2D-Image-Into-3D-Using-Blender .Is that what I need

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a simple way to do that, and certainly not one that looks good. Here's what I do, using an example from one of my own projects. This is what it looks like without the finishing details, just the UV mapping/modeling done:

[image]

And here is the texture that is applied, which is where you want to get to:

[image]

First, I had to model the chair as a whole (which for what looks like you want should be much simpler, there are tutorials on basic shape creation and extrusion modeling all over the place). Then I looked for textures that looked close to what I wanted and applied them to the individual parts (see [Adding UV mapping to mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/adding-uv-mapping-to-mesh)), giving me the result I asked about in this question: [Possible to bake texture to new UV map?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map)

You can then brush in details on the edges in something like Photoshop or GIMP.

Comment: .Thanks,I'm newbie in blender and graphics.Could you give me a tutorial source for Making a model ,Please?

Comment: .Thanks,I'm newbie in blender and graphics.Could you give me a tutorial source for Making a model ,Please?

Comment: Check out Blender Cookie's series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1DnYxd3iTw